# like button on mobile site redirects to PC login page when a user is not logged in

Tags: plugins, facebook-like

what I want is to redirect the user to m.facebook.com/login.php?.....(mobile login page) instead of PC login page.
When we use dialogs, we can specify *display=touch* to specify display mode for smartphone, but like button plugin doesn't have this kind of option as far as I read document
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

I think facebook should detect user's device and display an appropriate login page.
At least, share button redirects to the appropriate login page.
If their is a way we can specify it, I want to know. I'm using iframe version of the plugin, so far.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: I reported this as a [bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/266544906769261) and they assigned this.